# drag & click на одном элементе JS

Tags: javascript, drag-n-drop, click

Есть такой код:

```
                $this.Move = false;
                Block.mousedown(function (e) {
                    $this.Move = false;
                    let target  =$(e.target);
                    if (target.is(Block) || target.closest(Block).length > 0) {
                        console.log('start moved');
                        Block.attr('data-move', true);
                        let pOffset = $(e.target).closest(Block).offset();
                        localStorage.setItem('relOX', Math.round(e.pageX - pOffset.left));
                        localStorage.setItem('relOY', Math.round(e.pageY - pOffset.top));
                    }
                });

                Block.mouseup(function (e) {
                    if($this.Move) {
                        console.log('pin');
                        if(Block.attr('data-move').bool()) {
                            Block.attr('data-move', false);
                            Block.attr('data-moved', false);

                            let pWidth = $('body').innerWidth();
                            let pMiddle = pWidth / 2;
                            let pHeight = $('body').innerHeight();

                            let pos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('online-icon-pos'));
                            if (pos.x < pMiddle) {
                                Block.css({'top': pos.y, 'left': (pos.x = 0)});
                            } else if (pos.x > pMiddle) {
                                Block.css({'top': pos.y, 'left': (pos.x = (pWidth - Number(openChat.outerWidth(true))))});
                            } else {
                                Block.css({'top': pos.y, 'left': (pos.x = 0)});
                            }
                            localStorage.setItem('online-icon-pos', JSON.stringify({y: pos.y, x: pos.x}));
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log('open');
                        Block.attr('data-move', false);
                        Block.attr('data-moved', false);

                        $(this).fadeOut(200, function () {
                            block.fadeIn(200, function () {
                                $(this).animate({
                                    right: 0
                                }, 200);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    $this.Move = false;
                });

                $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
                    //if(!$this.Move) return;
                    if(Block.attr('data-move').bool()) {
                        $this.Move = true;
                        let relX = Number(localStorage.getItem('relOX'));
                        let relY = Number(localStorage.getItem('relOY'));

                        let y = e.pageY - relY;
                        let x = e.pageX - relX;

                        localStorage.setItem('online-icon-pos', JSON.stringify({y: y, x: x}));

                        Block.css({'top': y, 'left': x});

                        Block.attr('data-moved', true);
                    }
                });
```

`Block` - элемент по которому кликают или перемешают.

`block` - элемент который должен открыться при клике на `Block`

Проблема в том что простой клик не отрабатывает. Перемещение работает, а если просто нажать то нет. Консоль выведет: `start move` и при отпускании `pin`.

Что не так в коде?

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что `click` и `drag` содержат одинаковые события `mousedown` и `mouseup` поэтому отличить их друг от друга сложно. Единственное отличие в событии `mousemove` при драге. Чтобы отличить одно от другого, можно использовать подобный код:

```
var flag = 0;
var element = someElement;
element.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
    flag = 0;
}, false);
element.addEventListener("mousemove", function(){
    flag = 1;
}, false);
element.addEventListener("mouseup", function(){
    if(flag === 0){
        console.log("click");
    }
    else if(flag === 1){
        console.log("drag");
    }
}, false);
```

В данном случае при клике или драге выводится соответствующее действие в консоль, как адаптировать его под свои нужды я думаю поймете.